# PyCharm - indentation of {% block name %} tags with Reformat Code

Tags: pycharm, reformatting

Is it possible to do not indent children of `{% block %}` django tag when Reformat Code?

I'd like to have Reformated Code:

```
{% block name %}
<div>
    <p>Some text.</p>
</div>
{% endblock name %}
```

No:

```
{% block name %}
    <div>
        <p>Some text.</p>
    </div>
{% endblock name %}
```